# Is it possible to run a webdav fuse client with no root access?

Tags: filesystems, mount, non-root-user, webdav

I have seen examples showing how to use `davfs2` under linux, but each has involved one of these things:

1. Running `mount` as root
2. Adding an entry to `/etc/fstab`
3. Running `mount.davfs` setuid, which, alas, still requires an entry in `/etc/fstab`

Can this be avoided? If not, what aspect of webdav prevents it, more than for, e.g. sshfs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Davfs2 isn't implemented like a normal FUSE filesystem. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davfs2) and the documentation mention that it can work on top of either [Coda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_%28file_system%29) or [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), but the [project description](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2) doesn't mention FUSE (and hints at native integration). The [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/davfs2) does not depend on FUSE, and the binary it ships only runs as root. This is not intrinsic to WebDAV, it's just the way Davfs2 is implemented.

There are other WebDAV filesystem built on FUSE: [Fusedav](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/fusedav/), [Wdfs](http://noedler.de/projekte/wdfs/). Fusedav seems to be present in more distributions, but [wdfs works better with some broken servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25015/how-to-copy-someones-else-folders-from-public-me-com-with-a-wget-like-tool/25046#25046). These will work as long as you're allowed to use FUSE on your system.

Comment: I couldn't get fusedav to build but wdfs worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Alas, wdfs is no longer maintained.

Comment: Are there any updates here? Both Fusedav and Wdfs are outdated by a long way (2006 and 2007), which makes them very hard to install on new systems (never mind the security issues that come with it). Surely there must be answer to this question with newer than 13 year old software?

Comment: @SebastianMüller Probably, but I haven't used DAV in years and I haven't kept up with DAV-related tooling.

Comment: Same for me, if fact, one of the reasons is exactly the discussed issue here. Often I need to download webdav data on a cluster I dont have root access. Sometimes even ftp doesn't work and I end up downloading on my local PC and upload to the cluster which clearly is a big waste but I don't see how else I'd do this.