# How to copy someone's else folders from public.me.com with a wget-like tool?

Tags: scripting, wget, webdav, hosting-services, protocols

How can I copy a folder from http://public.me.com/ (a service related to [iDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDisk), or [MobileMe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me.com)) to my local filesystem with a Unix tool (like *wget*, **a command-line non-interactive tool**)?

The problem is that the web interface is actually a complex Javascript-based thing rather than simply exposing the files. (Even *w3m* can't browse, e.g., https://public.me.com/rudchenko.)

My goal is to update the local copy from time to time non-interactively, and to put the command to download the files to a script, so that other people can run the script and download the files.

A *wget*-like (*rsync*-like, *git pull*-like) tool will suit me, or a combination of mounting a network filesystem via FUSE and then using standard Unix commands to copy the directories will do.

I've read in the Wikipedia articles (which I refer to above) that Apple provides [WebDAV access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV#cite_note-8) to these services, and I've also read about *cadaver*, a *wget*-like WebDAV client, but I can't figure out which address I should use to access the folders at http://public.me.com/ read-only (anonymously).

Perhaps Gilles' comment (that WebDAV isn't currently used) is true, but still there seems to be some WebDAV stuff behind the scene: the URL passed to the browser for downloading an archive with a directory (after pressing the "download selected files" button at the top of the web interface) looks like this:

```
https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko/SEM%20Sep21%201%20TO%20PRINT.zip?webdav-method=ZIPGET&token=1g3s18hn-363p-13fryl0a20-17ial2zeu00&disposition=download
```

-- note that it mentions "WebDAV". (If you are curious, I tried to re-use this URL as an argument for *wget*, but it failed:

```
$ LC_ALL=C wget 'https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko/SEM%20Sep21%201%20TO%20PRINT.zip?webdav-method=ZIPGET&token=1g3s18hn-363p-13fryl0a20-17ial2zeu00&disposition=download'
--2011-11-21 01:21:48--  https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko/SEM%20Sep21%201%20TO%20PRINT.zip?webdav-method=ZIPGET&token=1g3s18hn-363p-13fryl0a20-17ial2zeu00&disposition=download
Resolving public.me.com... 23.32.106.105
Connecting to public.me.com|23.32.106.105|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-11-21 01:21:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.
$
```

)

(I'm using a GNU/Linux system.)

Comment: The [MobileMe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me.com) article states that iTools (an earlier service) supported WebDAV, it doesn't say anything about MobileMe (the current incarnation). You can download individual files with wget (`https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko/path/to/file`) but I don't see a way of listing directories. Consider another file sharing service.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks for your attention to the question anyway!

Comment: Will try the intsructions from http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1774 : "If you're using a WebDAV application on another operating system, enter the following as the location to open: https://public.me.com/membername or https://idisk.me.com/membername-Public (where membername is the other person's member name. For example, if the member name is "Emily_Parker", you would connect to https://public.me.com/emily_parker or https://idisk.me.com/emily_parker-Public). You need to know the member's public password in order to read from or write to the folder."

Comment: Interestingly, `fusedav -D https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko` (note the `/ix`) is able to list some file names but ultimately fails with some “PROPFIND failed: 405 Method Not Allowed” errors. It looks like there's a partial implementation of WebDAV. Maybe you can find a client that sticks to the implemented subset.

Comment: This service has been terminated recently. -- http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64209/4908

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That server is clearly running a partial or broken implementation of WebDAV. Note that you need to connect to an URL like https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko, not the normal URL https://public.me.com/rudchenko. I tried several clients:

- With a normal HTTP downloader such as wget or curl, I could download a file knowing its name (e.g. `wget  https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko/directory/filename`), but was not able to obtain a directory listing.
- [FuseDAV](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/fusedav/), which would have been my first choice, is unable to cope with some missing commands. It apparently manages to list the root directory (visible in the output from `fusedav -D`) but eventually runs some request that returns “PROPFIND failed: 404 Not Found” and locks up.
- [Nd](http://www.gohome.org/nd/) lacks a list command.
- [Cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/) works well, but lacks a recursive retrieval command. You could use it to obtain listings, then retrieve individual files as above.

  It's not perfect, and there is a problem specifically in this case: *cadaver*'s `mget` [fails to treat args with wildcards that expand to filenames with spaces](https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26649).
- [Davfs2](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2) works very well. I could mount that share and copy files from it. The only downside is that this is not a FUSE filesystem, you need root to mount it or an entry in `/etc/fstab`.
- The FUSE-based [wdfs](http://noedler.de/projekte/wdfs/)-1.4.2-[alt0.M51.1](http://sisyphus.ru/en/srpm/Branch51/wdfs/) worked very well in this case, requiring no root (only permissions for `/dev/fuse`).

  ```
  mkdir viewRemote
  wdfs https://public.me.com/ix/rudchenko/ viewRemote
  rsync -a viewRemote/SEM*TO\ PRINT* ./
  fusermount -u viewRemote
  rmdir viewRemote
  ```

(Of course, a simple `cp` instead of `rsync` would work well in this example; `rsync` was chosen merely for extra diagnostics about the difference when we would update the copy.)

(Apart from wdfs, I tried these commands on a Debian squeeze system. Your mileage may vary.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! As for using *cadaver* in this case, ultimately, I didn't want to mess up with parsing the output of *cadaver* to get the filenames (because it formats the listings "nicely" with spaces, which makes it not so nice for automatic processing). And *cadaver*'s `mget` [fails to treat args with wildcards that expand to filenames with spaces](https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26649) (at least, my version). But I found the FUSE-based wdfs-[1.4.2-alt0.M51.1](http://sisyphus.ru/ru/srpm/Branch51/wdfs/), which worked well for me.

Comment: @imz Thanks for reporting back. Do you know if this “alt” version of wdfs is required, or does the [official version](http://noedler.de/projekte/wdfs/) work too? By the way, you may want to write your own answer about wdfs.

Comment: AFAIU there are no substantial patches to the original source in the "alt" package, so I guess the "official" build will work the same.(The patches can be examined at http://sisyphus.ru/en/srpm/Branch51/wdfs/patches or the complete repo for building the package--following the links at http://sisyphus.ru/en/srpm/Branch51/wdfs/gear--in http://git.altlinux.org/people/elly/packages/?p=wdfs.git , http://git.altlinux.org/people/elly/packages/?p=wdfs.git;a=blob;f=.gear/rules;h=34f21e725f8f53a17cbd4dd3bb5cf14977d17ae6;hb=HEAD . The gear rules seem suggest that the pkger has just imported the orig tar)

Answer (score 1):

There are also some special scripts and a tool (`wget-warc`) to download the content of https://public.me.com/ user's folders -- https://github.com/ArchiveTeam/mobileme-grab/blob/master/dld-me-com.sh (and see the containing repo). (Found via http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=MobileMe#How_to_help_archiving.)

Internally, the script seems to compose WebDAV requests and use then the responses , e.g.:

```
# step 1: download the list of files

if [[ "$domain" =~ "public.me.com" ]]
then

  # public.me.com has real WebDAV

  # PROPFIND with Depth: infinity lists all files
  echo -n "   - Discovering urls (XML)..."
  curl "https://public.me.com/ix/${username}/" \
       --silent \
       --request PROPFIND \
       --header "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"" \
       --header "Depth: infinity" \
       --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DAV:propfind xmlns:DAV="DAV:"><DAV:allprop/></DAV:propfind>' \
       --user-agent "${USER_AGENT}" \
     > "$userdir/webdav-feed.xml"
  result=$?
  if [ $result -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo " ERROR ($result)."
    exit 1
  fi
  echo " done."

  # grep for href, strip <D:href> and prepend https://public.me.com
  grep -o -E "<D:href>[^<]+" "$userdir/webdav-feed.xml" | cut -c 9- | awk '/[^\/]$/ { print "https://public.me.com" $1 }' > "$userdir/urls.txt"
  count=$( cat "$userdir/urls.txt" | wc -l )

elif
```

Yes, they also use "https://public.me.com/ix/${username}/", note the "**/ix/**" infix in the URL! Not the normal URL -- [the same thing as Gilles discovered in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25046/4319).