# mounting dropbox (for exploring the files)

Tags: wget, fuse, dropbox, hosting-services, protocols

I want to simply be able to explore a dropbox filesystem, without much additional load on CPU, memory, storage (i.e., without saving copies of the remote files locally). It seems that the official client consumes much reosurces (and would do unneccessary operations like syncing) -- http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/3179/dropbox-memory-usage-on-linux.

Can one simply mount it (say, with FUSE, and without copying the files locally) and explore the files with the usual Unix utilities (`ls`, `du`, `cp`)? ([I wanted something similar for public.me.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25015/4319): `wget -r`-like or FUSE.)

[Dropbox-Uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader#readme) (a bash script using dropbox API to access it) could help to access dropbox in a Unix way. But unfortunately it doesn't support recursive downloading of directories (like `wget -r`), that's why I'd rather have a FUSE wrapper on top of it.

Comment: Now I learned that Dropbox-Uploader is in [a package in ALT](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/dropbox-uploader), my "home" distro.

Comment: https://thelig.ht/code/dbxfs/

Answer (score 8):

FUSE Filesystem 4 Dropbox can be found here: https://github.com/realriot/ff4d

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to DropFuse, you have also FuseDropbox: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fusedropbox/

Comment: It seems to be a stub project.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a project on GitHub](https://github.com/arekzb/dropfuse)

It's pretty old, but seems to address your issue.

Comment: But it works only for "publicly shared folders" (per summary on the project's page). I was interested in mounting a dropbox without making it public...